# NPM hanging on installing package 'zos'

Tags: npm, npm-install

Installing an NPM package (in this case 'zos') hangs at :

`>npm install zos`

`fetchMetadata: sill resolveWithNewModule http-https@1.0.0 checking installable status`

Seems kind of strange as this has only recently started occurring. Other packages seem not to have this issue...

I am using the following environment:
Arch Linux
Node v11.9.0
NPM v6.9.0

I can install other npm packages without issues (eg, lodash, truffle, web3)

Answer (score 0):

OK, I managed to fix the issue... last week I was having some issues with internet access in a new location with wifi so I had to hack around a bit with my /etc/resolv.conf file to get general internet access again... turns out that while that fixed my general browsing it had a knock on effect on npm installs!

So in summary to fix the issue I replaced my /etc/resolve.conf file which had only the following line in it:

```
# Generated by NetworkManager
nameserver 192.168.0.1
```

with a previous version of the file I had saved which had the following contents:

```
nameserver 127.0.0.53
options edns0
```

And Walah! Everything works again, including the 'npm install zos'....

Thanks to anyone who was looking into this for me!

Cheers
Rick